# Understanding a periodic discontinuous function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, continuity, periodic-functions

This is from an example in my PDE text. It's something I should probably know, but maybe I am just reading the wording wrong.

The text (Asmar as it happens, section 2.1) gives the following example of a periodic function: it's a set of lines that have slope -x, one of which is $f(x)=(-x+1)$ and the next to the left is $(-x-1)$ and to the right would be $(-x+2)$. But they aren't continuous (I wish I could draw the darn thing here). Anyhow, it says to consider the function in a couple of different ways. from the interval $0 \le x \lt 2$ and $-1 \le x \lt 1$.

The picture shows a series of lines with slope -1, each extending from 1 to -1 on the y-axis, if that gives any idea.

Then it says that in the interval $0 \le x \lt 2$ the function is a piece of the straight line $f(x)=-x+1 $ if $0 \le x \lt 2$. So far so good. But then it says that $f(x+2) = f(x)$ describes $f$ for all other values of x. But it doesn't! if you plug in any number outside of that interval you get numbers way out of the range of 0 to 2.

On top of that, it says that looked at from the interval $-1 \le x \lt 1$ the graph is 2 straight lines (again, I'm OK with that). So we have the relation 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x-1,  & \text{if $-1 \le x \lt 0$} \\
-x+1, & \text{if $\ \ \ 0 \le x \lt 1$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

and then the book says $f(x+2) = f(x)$ for all values of x outside $[-1,1)$. But that doesn't make sense to me, again if I plug in values outside of that interval I get a different answer. So am I just reading this wrong? The whole point is that the function is periodic, but it doesn't look periodic to me.

So am i just having  reading comprehension problem? Thanks.

Comment: You may use $\,f(x+2) = f(x)\,$ repetitively to deduce $\;f(x+4)=f(x+2)=f(x),\;f(x+6)=f(x),\cdots\;$ and also $f(x)=f(x-2),\;f(x)=f(x-4),\cdots$ and more generally $f(x+2\,k)=f(x)$ for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But that doesn't work. $f(1)$, for example, is 0 if I use the $0 \le x \lt 2$ interval, right? And if I put in 10, say, I get $f(4) = (-4+1) = -3$. That isn't between 1 and -1. SO what you are saying doesn't make any sense to me. What am I missing? Unless the whole point is that you only use the interval $0 \le x \lt 2$ as x that you add 2 to. But even then, it doesn't work.

Comment: The formula $f(x)=-x+1$ is valid only in $[0,2)$. In $[2,4)$ we define the value to be $f(x+2)=f(x)$ for $x\in [0,2)$. In fact the formula will be $f(x)=-x+3$ (and not $-x+2$ btw) for $x\in [2,4)$. If you look at the picture in the book you'll notice that the function is periodic of period $2$.

Comment: Arrgh. Where do you get that it becomes $f(x)=(-x+3)$? I put, say, 3 into f(x) and I get -3+1. That's -2. Or are you saying that in (for instance) any other interval you're just saying that f(whatever) = f(x)? I saw the picture in the book, it doesn't make any sense to me at all, because the numbers just don't come out right.

Comment: Hmmm... $f(3)=-3+3=0\,$ using $f(x)=(-x+3)$ ! And I say that $f(x+2\,k)=f(x)$ for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ no more no less. :-) We may continue with $f(x)=-x+5$ in $[4,6)$, $f(x)=-x+7$ in $[6,8)$ and so on (in general $f(x)=-x+1+2k$ in $[2k,2k+2)$).

Comment: for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: But why does the formula for f(x) = (-x+1) become -x+3? That's what is not making any sense to me. The formula is -x+1, dang it! the second piece of that (+1) doesn't change no matter what I put into x. Or does it? You're still not making sense to me and I am feeling stupid. It just seems like you are magically declaring that the numbers come out right.

Comment: You wrote $f(x)=-x+1$ if $0 \le x \lt 2$. This formula is valid **only** for $x\in [0,2)$ and you can't apply it elsewhere (see the picture and notice that the line segment stops at $x=0$ and $x=2$).

Comment: OK but if it is only valid for that interval what happens when I put values of x in that are outside it? That's what I am struggling with here -- if I use -x + 1, and plug in (x+2) where the -x is, for any x outside of [0,2) I don't get a periodic function. Unless the point is that outside of that we are saying that no matter what I put into f(here) it has to go back to being -x+1. I am trying to figure out how with f(3) the +1 became a 3.

Comment: If you use $f(x)=-x+1$ for $x$ in $[2,4)$ you'll need to shift the segment up of $+2$ (since you are too low of $2$), in $[4,6)$ you'll need to shift it up of $+4$ and so on. To understand my $-x+3,\;-x+5,\cdots$ you may too search the intersection of the lines with the vertical line $x=0$ : this will be at $y=1$ in $[0,2)$, at  $y=3$ in $[2,4)$ and so on. If $f(x+2k)=f(x)=-x+1$ for $x\in [0,2)$ then $f(y)=-y+2k+1$ $y:=x+2k\; \in [2k,2k+2)$.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now, the only way that f(whatever) = f(x) on any interval outside [0,2) is if you shift it, and that shift has to be some number (like 2 in this case). Thanks for bearing with me. My reading comprehension is terrible.

Comment: Glad it cleared things. Note that the shift trick doesn't apply in general (ex. $f(x)=x^2$ in $[0,2)$ will be $f(y)=(y-2)^2$ for $y$ in $[2,4)$ and not $f(y)=y^2-K$ : in general the shift is on the parameter and not the result !). In case of 'mental blocking' switching activities may help to get your mind free ! Fine continuation,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments let's try to rephrase all this in a (possibly) clearer way :

We start with : 
$$\tag{1}f(x)=-x+1\quad\text{if $\,x \in[0,2)$}$$

and will use the recurrence $\,f(x+2)=f(x)\,$ for any real $x$ rewritten as : 
$$\tag{2}f(x)=f(x-2)\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$

This implies that for $\,x$ in $[2,4)\,$ we may apply $(1)$ to $\,(x-2)$ in $[0,2)$ to get :
$$f(x)\overset{(2)\\}=f(x-2)\overset{(1)\\}=-(x-2)+1=-x+3\quad\text{if $\,x \in[2,4)$}$$
This corresponds to an horizontal shift of $2$ at the right of the graph of $f(x)$ in $[0,2)$.
(as explained the vertical shift doesn't generalize to other functions $f$ and should be forgotten)

We may continue for $\,x$ in $[4,6)\,$ so that $\,(x-4)$ will be in $[0,2)$ to get :
$$f(x)\overset{(2)\\}=f(x-2)\overset{(2)\\}=f(x-4)\overset{(1)\\}=-(x-4)+1=-x+5\quad\text{if $\,x \in[4,6)$}$$

We may obtain values for intervals in $\mathbb{R^-}$ using $\,f(x)=f(x+2)$.

The general formula for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ will be :
$$\tag{3} f(x)=\cdots=f(x-2k)=-(x-2k)+1\quad\text{if}\ x \in [2k,2k+2)$$

---

We may apply the same method to the $[-1,1)$ interval :

$$\tag{4}f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x-1,  & \text{if $\;-1 \le x \lt 0$} \\
-x+1, & \text{if $\quad 0 \le x \lt 1$}  \\
\end{cases}$$
and obtain more generally for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ :

$$\tag{5}f(x)=f(x-2k)=\begin{cases}
-(x-2k)-1,  & \text{if $\quad 2k-1 \le x \lt 2k$} \\
-(x-2k)+1, & \text{if $\quad 2k \le x \lt 2k+1$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Hoping all this will be less confusing,

Comment: it does, and thanks so much. I don't know why i was having such a problem...